# Codeigniter: Change form_open action value with javascript

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Working on a Login/Signup form which has the same `Email and Password` fields. I have to buttons at the end of the form:

```
<input class="loginButton" type="submit"  name="submit" value="Login">
<input class="loginButton" type="submit"  name="submit" style="display:none;" value="Sign Up">
```

Based on the user selection I will keep show/hibe between these two buttons.
Is there way I can toggle between action url of `create_user` and `login`.

> I am using `ion_auth` as login framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `show/hide` buttons depending on user's selection you can also change the action of your `form`, using something like this, (it's an idea but your case is different)

```
    $('form > input:button').on('click', function(){
        var action = $('form').attr('action') == 'myAction.php' ? 'someAction.php' : 'myAction.php' ;
        $('#myForm').attr('action', action);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/GHcNr/)

This will change the action to `someAction.php` if it's action is set to `myAction.php`, and it'll set the action to `myAction.php` when it's set to `someAction.php`.

**But**, in your case, I think, you should use, something like this (pseudo code)

```
if(login button is visible){
    // set action to login
}
else {
    // set action to create_user
}
```